# Не проигрывается mp3 на мобильных броузерах

Tags: php, аудио, header

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с проблемой. Для избавления от прямых ссылок на файлы, отдаю их через пхп-скрипт. С ПК все работает отменно, треки прослушиваются без проблем, но с большенством мобильных браузеров возникает ситуация, при которой медиа файл очень долго подгружается, где-то на пол минуты дольше всей страницы(иногда еще дольше). 
Для отдачи файла использую следующую функцию:

```
function get_file($filename, $mimetype='audio/mpeg') {
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 200 OK');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Content-Type: ' . $mimetype);
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('r', filemtime($filename)));
    header('ETag: ' . sprintf('%x-%x-%x', fileinode($filename), filesize($filename), filemtime($filename)));
    header('Content-Length: ' . (filesize($filename)));
    header('Connection: close');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . basename($filename) . '";');

    readfile($filename);
} else {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
    header('Status: 404 Not Found');
}
exit; }
```

грешу на заголовки, гугл рабочего варианта так и не дал. Заранее спасибо!

UPD: заметил что подобный баг есть не на всех версиях андроида. Так на 4.2 и 4.3 этой проблемы не возникает.

Comment: почему бы сам фаил не отдать как статичный?

Comment: такой вариант не подходит, так как это палит местонахождение файла, а ради этого все и затеелось

Comment: ok создаём tmp файл отдаём после удоляем

Comment: При высокой посещаемости ресурса будет очень большая нагрузка на винчестер, плюс значительно увеличется объем данных на диске, что тоже не самое хорошее решение.